# making different action in a form in symfony 4

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony4

I'm trying to make a symfony form with a booking system, the user selects the number of tickets in my first form, then he will be redirected to a different route if he chooses one ticket or two tickets.

Here is my controller :

```
public function home(Request $request, )
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
                 ->add('numberOfTickets', ChoiceType::class, [
                     'attr' => [
                         'class' => 'form-control'
                     ],
                     'choices' => [
                         '1' => 1,
                         '2' => 2,
                         '3' => 3,
                         '4' => 4,
                         '5' => 5,
                     ]
                 ])

                 ->setAction($this->generateUrl('ticket'))                     ->getForm();
```

How can I make a different action depending on the choice in my form, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to extend your controller. Make the route available for both GET and POST requests.

```
public function home(Request $request, )
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
                 ->add('numberOfTickets', ChoiceType::class, [
                     'attr' => [
                         'class' => 'form-control'
                     ],
                     'choices' => [
                         '1' => 1,
                         '2' => 2,
                         '3' => 3,
                         '4' => 4,
                         '5' => 5,
                     ]
                 ])

                 ->setAction($this->generateUrl('ticket'))->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
         $formData = $form->getData();
         switch($formData['numberOfTickets']){
             case 1:
                   return $this->redirectToRoute('routeForOneTicket');
    }

}

return $this->render('template', ['form' => $form->createView()]);
```

Not very pretty but it is a way. I don't know your application but is it wise to invest some time in getting to learn form classes: https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes.